# Facebook Business Page not showing me who has liked my posts in groups

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-groups

When my business page posts in a group, I can see that a set amount of people have liked that post. However, when I click to see who has liked the post (and invite them to my business page), on mobile it just says '0' and will not show me anything.

On desktop, it says 'Sorry, this content isn't available at the moment
The link you followed may have expired, or the Page may only be visible to an audience that you aren't in'.

I've tried on a few different groups and tried with another admin, but no luck..